# Angular 11.0.5 production build - Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: angular, webpack

In production build (i.e. `ng b --prod`) of Angular 11.0.5, the web page output has the following error:

[image]

If I were to disable optimization during production build (i.e. via `ng b --prod --optimization=false`), the problem disappears.

My suspicion is the circular reference was accidentally created during one of the Webpack processes.

Thanks.

[Edit1]: After including the source map, the error is as below:

[image: Detailed error]

`edit-form.service.ts:11` is referring to: `export class EditFormService extends BehaviorSubject<Opportunity[]>`

Top snippet from edit-form.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Opportunity } from 'src/app/shared/models/opportunity.model';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { APIService } from '../../api/API.service';
import { SharepointRequest } from 'src/app/shared/models/sharepoint.model';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EditFormService extends BehaviorSubject<Opportunity[]> {
    constructor(private APIService: APIService) {
        super(Array<Opportunity>());
    }
```

Notice that I have indeed initialised the constructor (i.e. via `super(Array<Opportunity>());`. At lost as to where to from here.

**I am looking for advice to take the troubleshooting further.**

Comment: Can you build the app with `ng build --prod --sourceMaps`? This will also create the related source files so that you can see where the error actually occurs. Please be aware that if you deploy to public, others can see the source, too.

Comment: Syntax to use: `ng b --prod --source-map=true` for Angular 11.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the `extends BehaviourSubject<...>`?

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, I do not know why; I had merely copied and adapted the code from the telerik website (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/external-editing/) --> View Source --> `edit.service.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there is a circular dependency going on.

Using madge (https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) and by running the command `npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./`, I was able to locate a circular dependency in `opportunity.model.ts` and resolved it.